# Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant) while accessing Flutter theme info

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying use the theme that I have defined in the the main.dart file but I am always getting this error when I try to access it via

```
color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor;,
```

> Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant) Const variables must be
> initialized with a constant value. Try changing the initializer to be
> a constant expression

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hello there',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Lato',
      ).copyWith(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF051F40),
        accentColor: Color(0xFFF25836),
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Show the code that triggers the error.  Most likely you are attempting to use `const` for a case where it is not allowed, and you therefore just need to remove it.

Comment: @jamesdlin thank you! It worked

Comment: Please, mark as answered.

Comment: "It worked" what worked? I see no `const` on the code, you should explain the answer and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Theme.of(context) inside or under a widget that has been created as const.

Here, the const on SizedBox is going to create the problem:

```
    return <Widget>[
      const SizedBox(
        height: 130,
        child: DrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ...
    ];
```

Neither the SizedBox or the DrawerHeader can be const, so you're left with:

```
    return <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: 130,
        child: DrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ...
    ];
```